# How to send Jenkins build number as parameter in shell command which will get executed after build ends

Tags: python, jenkins, testing, build, automation

i am running a python script every time, after a Jenkins build fails or gets aborted.
In that script i want to pass the Build Number so that i have this info in the script and use it accordingly.

Can someone help me please to understand how i should pass this build number as parameter to my shell command?

[image: py-postbuild]
[image: build-num]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shoud use  `"Execute Windows Batch Command"` if you access enviornment variable using `%`.
Using `"Execute Windows Batch Command"` you can use as below:

```
echo %BUILD_NUMBER%
C:\\Python38\\python.exe C:\\python-workspace\\hello_test.py %BUILD_NUMBER%
```

If you want to execute with shell then you can access using `$` as `$BUILD_NUMBER`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But does this -> `BUILD_NUMBER` really exist then or i should set it somewhere ?

Comment: @Marialena it is an Jenkins environmental variable so you dont have to set it. You can see all the list of environment  variables at : ``http://localhost:8080/env-vars.html/``. Let me know if you need any more information. ``$BUILD_NUMBER`` shall work for you

Comment: @Marialena if this works for you then request you to accept the answer

Comment: I have changed to as you said with the `$` in front, and i can see in jenkins logs of my build that it didn't work: `Running script  : python.exe sendemail.py LoginOld ABORT $BUILD_NUMBER`

Comment: @Marialena Can you check using ``${BUILD_NUMBER}`` and also can you see the environmental variable in the link ``http://localhost:8080/env-vars.html/``

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately.. i just got this in the logs: `python.exe sendemail.py LoginOld ABORT ${BUILD_NUMBER}` ... In the env page i can see the same: `BUILD_NUMBER - 
The current build number, such as "153".`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234337/discussion-between-altaf-and-marialena).

Comment: Seems like this: `%BUILD_NUMBER% ` solved my issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the **Postbuild Task plugin** which executes the script as a shell script, and therefore you should use the shell parameter syntax which is `$YOUR_PARAM`

In your case just update your code to use `$BUILD_NUMBER` instead of `%BUILD_NUMBER%`

Comment: I changed it but i can see from the logs that it just prints `$BUILD_NUMBER` instead of the actual number.

Comment: At the end this worked: `%BUILD_NUMBER%`. Thanks for the help.